# jQuery - apply class to an element with highest number

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="num1">4,8</div>  
<div class="num11">2,37</div>  

<div class="num2">3,5</div>  
<div class="num21">1,85</div> 

<div class="num3">5,7</div>  
<div class="num31">2,8</div> 

etc...
```

Now, what I would like to do is add additional class to the divs numX and numX1 where X is the number where the div has the highest value.

So, numX's should be tested, and I have that done so: [jsfiddleCode](http://jsfiddle.net/Hitman666/sQLu7/2/) but now I can't seem to figure out how to apply this additional class to the divs which match my selection. In the example above, I would have to add class to div classes num3 and num31, as div with class num3 has the highest value (5,7).

You will see in the jsfiddle code that I'm using the calculation jquery plugin, which also gives me problems with the comas (, ).

Any help is appreciated!

edit: Thanks so much to Louskan, Ill just cp the solution here in case jsfiddle disappears or sth like that:

```
var maxClass='';
var max=0;
$("div[class^='num']").filter(function(){
   return /^num\d$/.test($(this).attr("class"));
}).each(function() {
var val = $(this).html();
val = val.replace(",",".");
if (val > max) {
    max = val;
    maxClass = $(this).attr('class');
}
});

$("div[class^="+maxClass+"]").css('border', '1px red solid');
```

Once again: thank you!

Comment: what does do the method '.test()'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code : http://jsfiddle.net/sQLu7/11/

You can replace the css border with addClass.
Hope this help, your problem was that your t variable returned only the first element.

Edit oh and I actually retrieve only subelements, meaning if 31 is the highest then 3 won't be retrieved. Well you can adjust the code on your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 0;
var class;
$("div[class^='num']").each(function(){
    var float = parseFloat($(this).html().replace(',','.'));
    if (float > num) {
        num = float;
        class = $(this).attr('class');
    };
});
//$( '.' + class ).css('color', '#ff0000');
$( '.' + class ).addClass('selected');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/VREpt/1/